# GetAsyncKeyState returning fatal link error

Tags: c++, keyboard

I am trying to make a basic console game in c++ and when I try to use the `GetAsyncKeyState` in the following code:

```
   if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0){
        int y2 = (y - 1);
        switch(Map[y2][x]){
            case ' ':{
                Map[y][x] = ' ';
                y -= 1;
                Map[y2][x] = 'O';
            }
        }
    }
```

...but I keep getting the following error when I try to compile it:

```
    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetAsyncKeyState@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl Draw(void)" (?Draw@@YAXXZ)

    fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I am not sure if I need to include any libraries other than `iostream` and `windows.h`

Comment: I know other users have asked similar questions, but not exactly like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error comes from the linker. You have to link with `User32.lib` where the `GetAsyncKeyState` symbol is defined (actually it's an import library for the User32.dll). You can do it either by writing

```
#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")
```

in your .cpp file, or adding `User32.lib` to your linker command line.

Note that if you use Microsoft Visual Studio and create a non-empty Win32 project, then the required default Windows system libraries are already linked with. However, since you did not indicate how exactly do you compile and link, I won't expand more on this topic.